# Can I perform a 'non-global' grep and capture only the first match found for each line of input?

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

I understand that what I'm asking can be accomplished using awk or sed, I'm asking here how to do this using GREP.

Given the following input:

```
.bash_profile
.config/ranger/bookmarks
.oh-my-zsh/README.md
```

I want to use GREP to get:

```
.bash_profile
.config/
.oh-my-zsh/
```

Currently I'm trying

```
grep -Po '([^/]*[/]?){1}'
```

Which results in output:

```
.bash_profile
.config/
ranger/
bookmarks
.oh-my-zsh/
README.md
```

Is there some simple way to use GREP to only get the first matched string on each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can grep non `/` letters like:

```
grep -Eo '^[^/]+'
```

On another SO site there is another similar [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351566/how-to-print-only-a-first-match-from-each-line) with solution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `grep` for this at all.

```
cut -d / -f 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-o` option says to print every substring which matches your pattern, instead of printing each matching line. Your current pattern matches every string which doesn't contain slashes (optionally including a trailing slash); but it's easy to switch to one which only matches this pattern at the beginning of a line.

```sh
grep -o '^[^/]*' file
```

Notice the addition of the `^` beginning of line anchor, and the omission of the `-P` option (which you were not really using anyway) as well as the silly beginner error `{1}`.

(I should add that plain `grep` doesn't support parentheses or repetitions; `grep -E` would support these constructs just fine, of you could switch to toe POSIX BRE variation which requires a backslash to use round or curly parentheses as metacharacters. You can probably ignore these details and just use `grep -E` everywhere unless you really need the features of `grep -P`, though also be aware that `-P` is not portable.)